# React: Executing a setTimeout once on a "onChange"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to execute this function ONCE when a user starts typing on a TextField. My code currently looks like this:

```
  function startTimer() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCounter(counter - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

This is my return statement:

```
<TextField fullWidth rows="10" multiline="true" onChange={startTimer} />
```

Currently this function executes once, meaning when a user types one letter, the timer will go down by once second. I want the function to execute once and let the setTimeout / setInterval to keep executing so that the timer goes down.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't you write `onChange={startTimer()}` instead? or `onChange={() => startTimer()}`

Comment: @sameTbh what's the purpose of using the counter, if I may ask? Are you using it to store the number of characters?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? User types and timer is reset on each change, or simply start a count down when the first onChange occurs?

Comment: @Prateek Thapa I just want the timer to start counting down when the user starts typing on the TextField.

Comment: @Laszio Stahorski adding the parentheses calls that function right away. It's the same as using a "useEffect". I want the timer to start when the user first inputs into the TextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still salvage your `setTimeout` implementation. You can have a state for when the `startTimer` function has executed once, such that when the function has already executed and the timer has been set, the function will no longer execute again when the `onChange` event on `TextField` is invoked. In my example below, I set the counter to `60` initally `onChange` - you have not explicitly indicated in your code where it is defined.

```js
const TextField = (props) => {
  return <input {...props} />
}

function App(){

  const [timerStarted, setTimerStarted] = React.useState(false); // flag for when timer started
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  
  // function will execute only "once" and that is when the timerStarted is false (initially)
  function startTimer(_counter) {
    if(timerStarted === false){
      setCounter(_counter);
    }
    setTimerStarted(true); // set to true so that it won't get executed again when TextField "onChange" is invoked
  }
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
  
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if(counter > 0){
        setCounter(counter => counter - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
    
    console.log(counter);
    
    return ()=>clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [counter]) // setTimeout put inside useEffect so that that the counter decrements every x seconds

  return (
    <TextField onChange={()=>startTimer(60)} />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! it executes once cause you have use **setTimeout**  try **setInterval** instead.

```
function startTimer() {
if (counter > 0) {
  setInterval(() => {
    setCounter(counter - 1);
  }, 1000);
}  
}
```

Comment: setInterval does the same thing as setTimeout

Comment: @sameTbh nope setTimeout time out once after a certain interval but setInterval keeps on running in freq time interval

Answer (score 0):

Just move `setCounter(counter - 1);` out of `setTimout`

```
  function startTimer() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      setCounter(counter - 1);
      setTimeout(() => {
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: So the counter is still only decremented once and the timeout expires and does... nothing?

Comment: It depends on you what do you want the timer to do?

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things you need to do

- Ensure the timer starts once and only once
- Ensure the timer is cleaned up when component unmounts

I'd do something like the following

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initalCounterValue)

// hold the interval in a ref so you can clean it up when
// component unmounts (see below)
const intervalRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
  // clear the interval on component unmount if started
  return () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
    }
  }
})

const startTimer = () => {
  // only set the interval if not already started
  if (!intervalRef.current) {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      // you must use this 'function' form of the setter
      // to avoid making a closure over the value of counter
      //
      // i.e. DO NOT do setCounter(counter - 1)
      // as the value of counter will be constant at whatever it
      // was at the time startTimer() is called and will never change
      // so the counter will only update once
      setCounter(counter => counter - 1)
    }, 1000)
  }
}

return (
  ...
  <TextField fullWidth rows="10" multiline="true" onChange={startTimer} />
  ...
)
```

Of course you may also want to stop the counter manually. If so you'd add another function like this:

```
const stopTimer = () => {
  // possibly do something here with the value of counter when it was stopped
  doSomethingWithValueOfCounter(counter)

  clearInterval(intervalRef.current)

  // set counter value to initial value
  // and ref back to null so timer can be started again
  setCounter(initalCounterValue)
  intervalRef.current = null  
}

...

<button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop the timer</button>
```